# Run 'real VNC Viewer' in full screen mode

Tags: macos, fullscreen

## Full Screen Mode

After updating to Yosemite you can now run applications in 'Full Screen Mode' (Application runs in full screen without the OS X toolbar at the top) if it's supported.

## Problem

I am running 'real VNC viewer' to access my Raspberry Pi's screen over the network. The only issue is when I put 'VNC viewer' into full screen I still have the OS X toolbar at the top. Is there a way how to fix this?

## Before solution

[image]
As you can see, the toolbar and window buttons (quit, minimise and full screen) are visible.

## After solution (What I want)

[image]
The OS X toolbar an window buttons have now gone.

Is there a way on how to do this?

Comment: How do you put the app in full screen? Ctrl+Command+F does not work for your?

Comment: No. Its not supported by 'VNC viewer'. This is why I posted this question. Just tried ^⌘F and it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VNC viewer has it's own 'full screen' mode.

To access it, move your mouse to the top of the window (where the arrow is pointing) and click the full screen icon.

The only issue with this is you cannot view multiple desktops (using the trackpad gestures) without closing full screen mode.

To toggle full screen mode quickly you can press <kbd>F8</kbd> (<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>play/pause</kbd>) then when the menu pops up press <kbd>F</kbd>

[image: vnc toolbar sensitive area]

Comment: That works, however I cannot change between desktops with that mode. It will do for now! Thanks.